# BeagleBone Black CAN

Tags: beagleboneblack, can-bus

Is there some libs to work with CAN interface on BeagleBone Black?
Commands `cansend` and `candump` are working successful. Now I need to write program in C/C++ for CAN interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! cansend and candump uses SocketCAN API so you could make use of SocketCAN API in your code as well.